# How do i hyperlink a url in the json to the text inside the same JSON using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have a JSON structure as below:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "0",
    "_rev": "1",
    "url": "fb.com",
    "ownership": {
      "line": "social"
    },
    "id": 13,
    "hierarchies": [
      {
        "level": 30,
        "level40_desc": "",
        "pairing": "6950-9X",
        "level30_desc": "facebook",
        "level30_id": "6941-0P",
        "mirror": "",
        "level17_id": "1CMA",
        "fin_div": "M3",
        "id": "6941-0P"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "02ad9973a97f82db1c",
    "_rev": "1-8788cdde1205ca608a3",
    "url": "www.google.com",
    "ownership": {
      "line": "social"
    },
    "id": 159,
    "hierarchies": [
      {
        "level": 30,
        "level40_desc": "",
        "pairing": "6950-9L",
        "level30_desc": "google",
        "level30_id": "6941-9L",
        "mirror": "",
        "level17_id": "1CMA",
        "fin_div": "M3",
        "id": "6941-9L"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "01c555f2333a97f82e837",
    "_rev": "1-0101ae7cc842f43c9a40",
    "url": "www.twitter.com",
    "ownership": {
      "line": "social"
    },
    "id": 14,
    "hierarchies": [
      {
        "level": 30,
        "level40_desc": "",
        "pairing": "6950-8M",
        "level30_desc": "twitter",
        "level30_id": "6941-8M",
        "mirror": "",
        "level17_id": "1CMA",
        "fin_div": "M3",
        "id": "6941-8M"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

In controller I have this JSON to be in `vm.searchData`, there by in HTML display I'm displaying the data as

```
<div ng-repeat="item in vm.searchData track by $index">
    <div id="{{item.url}}">
        <a class="search-results" href="" ui-sref="." ng-repeat="item1 in item.hierarchies track by $index">{{item1.level30_desc}}-{{item1.level30_id}}</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

If I want to hyperlink the displayed element with the URL available in the JSON and clicking on hyperlink should open in a new Tab... How would I achieve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign the URL to the `href` attribute using the [`ng-href`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref) directive, and specify `target` as `_blank` to open the link in new tab:

```
<a class="search-results" ng-href="//{{item.url}}" target="_blank" ng-repeat ...
```

Just remember to remove `ui-sref` from the `a` tags as it may overwrite the URLs with UI router's state URLs. Additionally, since the URLs are without protocol in your data, it will be beneficial precede them with `//` to make them absolute.

**Working demo:**

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.searchData = [{
        "_id": "0",
        "_rev": "1",
        "url": "fb.com",
        "ownership": {
          "line": "social"
        },
        "id": 13,
        "hierarchies": [{
          "level": 30,
          "level40_desc": "",
          "pairing": "6950-9X",
          "level30_desc": "facebook",
          "level30_id": "6941-0P",
          "mirror": "",
          "level17_id": "1CMA",
          "fin_div": "M3",
          "id": "6941-0P"
        }]
      },
      {
        "_id": "02ad9973a97f82db1c",
        "_rev": "1-8788cdde1205ca608a3",
        "url": "www.google.com",
        "ownership": {
          "line": "social"
        },
        "id": 159,
        "hierarchies": [{
          "level": 30,
          "level40_desc": "",
          "pairing": "6950-9L",
          "level30_desc": "google",
          "level30_id": "6941-9L",
          "mirror": "",
          "level17_id": "1CMA",
          "fin_div": "M3",
          "id": "6941-9L"
        }]
      },
      {
        "_id": "01c555f2333a97f82e837",
        "_rev": "1-0101ae7cc842f43c9a40",
        "url": "www.twitter.com",
        "ownership": {
          "line": "social"
        },
        "id": 14,
        "hierarchies": [{
          "level": 30,
          "level40_desc": "",
          "pairing": "6950-8M",
          "level30_desc": "twitter",
          "level30_id": "6941-8M",
          "mirror": "",
          "level17_id": "1CMA",
          "fin_div": "M3",
          "id": "6941-8M"
        }]
      }
    ];
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <div ng-repeat="item in searchData track by $index">
    <div id="{{item.url}}">
      <a class="search-results" ng-href="//{{item.url}}" ng-repeat="item1 in item.hierarchies track by $index">{{item1.level30_desc}}-{{item1.level30_id}}</a></div>
  </div>
</div>
```